# could not find function "find_rtools"

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, rtools

R 3.5.1 windows 7
installed rTools35.exe
while checking if rtools is installed properly, getting an error:

> library(devtools)
>   find_rtools()
>   Error in find_rtools() : could not find function "find_rtools"

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to load "pkgbuild" for that version by running `library(pkgbuild)`. Then you can call `find_rtools()`.

```
> library(devtools)
> find_rtools()
Error in find_rtools() : could not find function "find_rtools"
> library(pkgbuild)

Attaching package: ‘pkgbuild’

The following object is masked from ‘package:devtools’:

    build

> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
```